# Creating batch file to start cygwin and execute specific command

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, cygwin, piping

I want to create a batch file thats start cygwin and executes a specific command (The command is to read a bash file and executes some command inside it).

This is the batch file that I have developed, it works to some extent. the cygwin terminal opens and tries to read the bash file, but cannot execute the commands inside:

```
@ECHO OFF

C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -li /cygdrive/c/(path-to-bash-file-location)/(MyBashFile)

PAUSE
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What is the specific error message you're getting from cygwin?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From your batch file, launch Cygwin's bash shell and use the login flag.  This provides a foundation for setting path and environment variables through your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` files. I believe this may be the source of your difficulties.

```
@ echo off
C:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login -c "cd ~/path/to/desired; ./mybashfile.sh"
```

If you provide more details about the nature of your bash file, I can be more specific.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much the hint about "--login" flag was very helpful.

Answer (score 14):

[Patrick Kelly's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7601529/patrick-kelly) points out that *not* running `bash` as a *login* shell in Cygwin may be the source of the problem.

Indeed: **Always run Cygwin `bash` as a *login* shell, because crucial initializations will otherwise not take place**; notably, the `$PATH` variable won't contain `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`, and the locale won't be set correctly.

In order to make `bash` start a *login* shell, the *bash executable* must be passed the `-l` option (or its longer alias, `--login`).

- To execute your script:

  - **in the *current* console window**, see [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7601529/patrick-kelly).

    - Note that unless the target script relies on a particular working directory, use of `-c` with separate `cd` and execution commands is not strictly necessary; something like the following will do:

      ```
      C:\cygwin64\bin\bash -l c:\path\to\your\script
      ```
  - **in `mintty.exe`**, the terminal application that Cygwin comes with (as you've tried):

    ```
    C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty /bin/bash -l c:\path\to\your\script
    ```

    - Note that executing `mintty` from a Command Prompt or batch file invariably opens a *new* console window, and does so *asynchronously*.

Note how a *Windows*-style path can (alternatively) be used to specify the target script (which means you could have used `c:\cygwin64\bin\bash` instead of `/bin/bash` too).

More importantly, note how an **explicit reference to the `bash` executable is required** in both cases, which contrasts with **what you tried**:

---

**Options you pass to `mintty.exe` are specific to *it* - they're *not* passed through to `bash`.**
Specifically, `mintty.exe` options you're using are (see all of them by running `mintty --help`):

- `-l, --log FILE|-` ... Log output to file or stdout
- `-i, --icon FILE[,IX]` ... Load window icon from file, optionally with index

Therefore, `-li` creates a log file named `i` in the current directory, because `i` is interpreted as the `l`'s option-argument, not as separate option `i`.

The specified script (`/cygdrive/c/...`) still executes, however - but, crucially, *not in a login shell*.

What you meant to do requires an explicit call to the `bash` executable, as demonstrated above, so that the options are interpreted by *Bash*:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty /bin/bash -li c:\path\to\your\script
```

Also, as noted, executing `mintty.exe` from a batch file invariably creates a *new* console window, and does so *asynchronously* - that is, your batch file immediately proceeds to the `PAUSE` command, irrespective of whether the `mintty.exe` process has terminated yet or not.

Obviously, whatever is output in that new window will not be visible in the original window.

---

#### Optional reading: interacting with a `mintty.exe` window:

**Caveat**: `mintty.exe` runs *asynchronously* even when using the usual `start /wait` approach from a batch file; that is, the following attempt to block a batch file / command prompt until `mintty.exe` terminates does *not* work:

```
start /wait "" "c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty" # !! DOES NOT WORK - still asynchronous
```

**When passed a script / command, the Bash session created by `mintty.exe` will invariably *exit* when the script terminates**, because `bash` - even when it's passed `-i` to indicate an *interactive* session - will automatically exit in that case.

**If all you need is to *inspect* the output after the script terminates**, run:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty -h always /bin/bash -l /cygdrive/c/path/to/bash-script
```

Note that no shell is running in that window once the script exits, so all you can do is *inspect* the script's output - nothing more.

**To keep a shell open**, you need a **workaround**:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\mintty /bin/bash -lc "/cygdrive/c/path/to/bash-script; exec /bin/bash"
```

Note that this creates a *new* shell instance after the script exits.

Comment: `mintty` is built for `windows` subsystem (GCC `-mwindows`) so the app doesn't attach to the existing console, that's why it acts "asynchronously". `bash` is built for `console` subsystem (GCC `-mconsole`) so attaches to the current console and blocks your command prompt.

Comment: @gavenkoa, the execution is asynchronous from the perspective of the calling shell: it launches the process, and control returns to it right away. Therefore, the term "asynchronous" seems appropriate to me. What would you call it? Understood that that `mintty.exe` is a GUI-subsystem application, but that alone doesn't explain the behavior, given that `start /wait` works fine for such applications (try `start /wait Notepad.exe`); I suspect that `mintty.exe` launches its GUI _indirectly_, via another process.

Comment: I checked `mintty` behavior with `procmon`: initial `mintty` creates second `mintty` and immediately exits. This explains `start /wait`: so I made wrong assumption that blocking is on terminal lock. Apparently `/wait` waits for child PID, so `mintty` implemented a trick to hide own PID. Tnx for explanation: I didn't know about `start /wait Notepad`!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @gavenkoa - thanks for digging deeper.