# Bash get pid of cygwin terminal

Tags: bash, git, cygwin, pre-commit-hook, github-desktop

I use the git pre-commit hook to run an autoformat-script `format-src.sh`
that is based on `clang-format`. Some developers use `github-desktop` where it is not
easy possible to install the `clang-format` package.
For this reason i decided to call cygwin bash from the precommit-hook.
In cygwin it is easy possible to install the `clang-format` package with cygwins package manager.

The call of the cygwin shell is done according to:
[Creating batch file to start cygwin and execute specific command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270097/creating-batch-file-to-start-cygwin-and-execute-specific-command)

***pre-commit***

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Format src accordingt to format-src.sh"

CYGWIN_DIR=c:/cygwin64/
PROJ_DIR=/cygdrive/c/Projekte/ExampleProj

eval '$CYGWIN_DIR/bin/mintty $CYGWIN_DIR/bin/bash --login -c "cd $PROJ_DIR; ./format-src.sh"'
```

My problem ist that the pre-commit hook seems not to wait until the cywin terminal mintty has finished the skript `format-src.sh`. Therfore the commit finishes while the auto-formater script still runs.

How can i wait until the the script that runs in mintty has finished ?

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of using `$!`. But as it turned out, `mintty` changed pid when the `format-src.sh` script fired. We will have to monitor its status from `ps`.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Format src accordingt to format-src.sh"

CYGWIN_DIR=c:/cygwin64/
PROJ_DIR=/cygdrive/c/Projekte/ExampleProj

eval '$CYGWIN_DIR/bin/mintty $CYGWIN_DIR/bin/bash --login -c "cd $PROJ_DIR; ./format-src.sh"'

echo "Monitor mintty status"
while true; do
    ps -s | grep mintty || break
    sleep 1
done
echo "Cygwin mintty finished"
```